# Passing a pointer by reference using accessor function in a class

Tags: c++, pointers

Using an accessor function, I am trying to pass a pointer by reference to another function.

This pointer is a private member of the class Skiplist and points to the head of a, yup, skip list.

I am needing to pass this head pointer to the insert function by reference so that I can change what the head pointer is pointing to if need be.

I can see that my accessor function is returning the address stored in head, not the address of head itself, but I can not for the life of me figure how to fix this.

The error I get is this:

```
pointer.cpp: In function 'int main()':
pointer.cpp:32:29: error: no matching function for call to 'Skiplist::insert(Nod
e*)'
  test.insert(test.get_head());
                             ^
pointer.cpp:32:29: note: candidate is:
pointer.cpp:17:8: note: void Skiplist::insert(Node*&)
   void insert(Node *&head);
        ^
pointer.cpp:17:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Node*' to 'No
de*&'
```

Here is a very stripped down version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:

    private:    
};

class Skiplist
{
    public:
        void insert(Node *&head);
        Node *get_head() const;

    private:
        int level_count;
        Node *head;
};

int main()
{
    Skiplist test;
    test.insert(test.get_head());
    return 0;
}

Node *Skiplist::get_head() const
{
    return head;
}

void Skiplist::insert(Node *&head)
{
    //bla bla bla
}
```

Comment: `get_head` returns a pointer, not a reference to a pointer.

Comment: `get_head()` returns by value, which will be a temporary and can't be bound to lvalue reference to non-const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Skiplist::get_head()` should return `Node *&` to return a reference. And since you want to allow it to modify `head`, you can't declare the member function `const`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:

    private:    
};

class Skiplist
{
    public:
        void insert(Node *& head);
        Node *&get_head();

    private:
        int level_count;
        Node *head;
};

int main()
{
    Skiplist test;
    test.insert(test.get_head());
    return 0;
}

Node *&Skiplist::get_head()
{
    return head;
}

void Skiplist::insert(Node *&head)
{
    //bla bla bla
}
```